# one ecs cluster or multiple ones?

Tags: amazon-ecs, producer-consumer

I have a single ECS Cluster where api server is running.

Now I would like to have producer/consumer system using sqs.
(producer is polling database and enqueue data and consumer dequeues data.)

I am thinking whether I should put them into one ecs cluster or have separare cluster.

what is the best way to achive this?
And Are there any pros and cons?

I assume that consumer procceses large and lots of data. So it should be scallable.

thank you

Comment: It's entirely up to you. It really only depends on if you want them to run on separate EC2 servers for some reason. If you are using Fargate instead of EC2 then there is really no difference in separate versus single cluster.